# Selecting rows with maximum value in Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I've got this rows in my Oracle database:

```
N783AS          6 WA
N794SW          2 WA
N407SW          2 WI
N471CA         10 WI
N479CA          6 WI
N494CA          5 WI
N495CA          7 WI
N496CA         12 WI
N498CA          9 WI
N506CA          8 WI
N507CA          6 WI
```

What I'd like to obtain is this:

```
N496CA         12 WI
N783AS          6 WA
```

So, what I should do is, somehow, obtain, for each state (third column), the row with the maximum value of the second column. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.col2 = (select max(t2.col2) from t t2 where t2.col3 = t.col3);
```

With an index on `(col3, col2)` this is probably the most performant solution, but it can return duplicates.  To avoid that, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col3 order by col2 desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Or, this might have the better performance under some circumstances:

```
select max(col1) keep (dense_rank first order by col2 desc), max(col2), col3
 from t
group by col3;
```